# Elasticsearch boosting, how to boost per value of matched the sub field in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have document like this:

```
{
"Title" : "test title1",
  "AssocQueries" : [
     {"Term":"title1", "Count" : 50},
     {"Term":"test title1", "Count" : 20},
     {"Term":"this is test title1", "Count" : 10}
  ]
}
```

The AssocQueries data are from BI system which indicates the counts of clicks on the document from certain query term.

I would like to boost the document per the value of "Count" field whose Term filed exactly match the query term.

Say, if search by "title1", boost with 50, if search by "test title" then boost with 20. The actual boost value could be number calculated from Count value.

Is it doable in Elasticsearch?